# Python encoding issue: degree sign and others

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape data from a webpage. I want to compare the website data  with text that is in a .txt document. However, I seem to be having encoding issues.

The website has the text "heat oven to 400°" The text also appears like this in "view source" (no html entities.)

The website is read using beautifulSoup:

```
source = "my url".read()
....
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
```

The text document was created by making a new text doc encoded as "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM". I then copy-pasted "heat oven to 400°" from the website into the text doc and saved.

The text file is read as

```
f = codecs.open('myfilename', encoding='utf-8')
```

When I compare the two strings, they are not equal, but I want them to be.

To see what is going on: In Eclipse, I split the two texts and, looking at the variables in debug mode, I see that the degree sign from BeautifulSoup appears as \xc2 \xb0. The degree sign from the text doc just appears as \xb0.

Why, and how do I fix it? I'm having this issue with many special chars so I need a general solution. Also, I will be copy-pasting data from several sites into the text doc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+beautifulsoup+encoding

Comment: You know the encoding of your text file and are using it appropriately, but the encoding of the website is not being taken into account. Basically, it only makes sense to compare bytes (as you are doing) if they're in the same encoding, or compare unicode strings (which requires taking the bytes and interpreting them using the correct encoding).

Comment: Your text doc appears not to be in UTF-8, in spite of your efforts. Or the HTML is somehow double-encoded (it's not exactly clear how you have diagnosed the difference; a simple hex dump of the files would help if you still want to add information).

Comment: Alright, figured it out. Looked again at how the website is encoded, like Cameron suggested. BeautifulSoup does automatically take encoding into account, correctly turning everything into unicode. I checked this by doing "print soup.originalEncoding". It's UTF-8 when I create the soup straight from the source. However, before creating the soup from the source, I do some text replacements using re.sub(). This is what alters the utf-8 of the source to something that BeautifulSoup doesn't recognize. So I will look at how I do the text replacements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Beautiful Soup doesn't have what it needs in order to detect the encoding correctly. You can give a hint by replacing BeautifulSoup(source) with BeautifulSoup(source, fromEncoding='UTF-8'). More options and information are online at "[Beautiful Soup Gives You Unicode, Dammit](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit)".

The bytes '\xc2\xb0' are what you get when the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode code point U+00B0 is mistaken for Beautiful Soup's last-resort guess at the encoding, which is Windows 1252.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is pretty much what turned out to be the issue, with a twist. I was altering the source before creating the soup. Beautiful then no longer recognized the encoding. See my comment above starting "Alright, figured it out".